# Cocoa Bound NSTableView (or NSOutlineView) Cell for "No Data"

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

Just wondering how I would achieve getting my NSOutlineView (or even a NSTableView) to display a cell (row) based on "no rows" from the Cocoa bound NSArrayController.

At the moment I have an NSOutlineView bound to an NSArrayController (I should really use a NSTreeController, but just playing around.)..

The bindings and working fine in terms of the data being bound (from CoreData). Using various sortDescriptors, it further sorts into alphabetical groups (much like the contacts app)...

When I'm trying to do is get my third cell, the one denoting "no data" / "no entries" to appear when there's nothing from the bindings.

Ay pointers would  be handy.

Thanks in advance.

Ade

Comment: In which row do you want to show this third cell?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is an extra view over the outlineview. The view is visible if the number of rows in the array/treecontroller is 0.

Comment: Thats not so easy if you're dabbling in the iterator views like "rows". I'm trying to avoid using an extra check at the end of the iteration to check if theres a "zero" view count

Comment: What I'm looking for is a "natural" zero view count, then a non zero view count